# Why redis.status returns "ready" even when I gave wrong port number?

Tags: redis

I wanted to verify the validity of redis access information before the process goes on.

I mean, I wanted to store data only when the port number is successfully being used by redis.

But redis.status returns "ready" even when I gave wrong port number like this :

```
{
  "port": 710000000,
  "host": "127.0.0.1"
}
```

Is it because `Offline Queue option` default is True?

and my nodejs app is here:

```
var redis = '';
...
redis = new Redis(config.redis.connectTo);
...

vmg.send(req, 'certification', redis, config, (error, callbackVmgResponse) => {
...
```

Before passing `redis` to the factor of the function `vmg`,

I want to check whether the connection of redis is valid.

Can I define the Validity of port number with redis.status ?

Comment: Maybe you can use Redis `ping` command and see if it returns `pong`?

Comment: Does this still happen if you have your redis instance running in a non default port (e.g, any port other than 6379)? In any case, if you just need to make sure the instance is running, ready and responsive, Mark's suggestion is the best (the ping command is commonly used for similar purposes).

Comment: Really appreciate for your answer, but I wondered why that code is successfully returning with wrong port number, and I've just discovered that is because there is default port a.k.a. 6379. Now I'm gonna find proper way to avoid auto connect to default port.. Do you have any suggestion?